# How can I use the physics package in mathjax for org-mode HTML export?

Tags: org-mode, latex, html, mathjax

I’m trying to use org-mode to export something as an HTML document, with MathJax equations. I know that [MathJax supports the physics package](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/physics.html), so it seems like it should be possible to tell emacs to tell MathJax to load `physics`. But how?

The code suggested in the link above is

```
window.MathJax = {
  loader: {load: ['[tex]/physics']},
  tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['physics']}}
};
```

so I tried putting variations of these lines in the document:

- `#+HTML_MATHJAX: loader: {load: ['[tex]/physics']} tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['physics']}}`
- `#+HTML_MATHJAX: load: ['[tex]/physics'] packages: {'[+]': ['physics']}`

But neither worked. What’s the right way to do this?

Example:

```
#+TITLE: Some physics
^^^ What can I put here to use the physics package?

$\ket{-}=\frac{\ket{0}-\ket{1}}{\sqrt{2}}$
```

**Edit**: I put one solution down below that uses pandoc.

Comment: Try simply export via pandoc to html5. No other settings. See supported symbols here: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros/index.html

Comment: Oh, I didn’t consider pandoc! That’s also worth trying. But still, when I run pandoc on this example file (via the shell, not through org-mode) I get errors, I think because pandoc also doesn’t know I need the `physics` package. I’ll update the question to be more specific.

Comment: I suggested html5 - not simply html. Take into account there is a package ```ox-pandoc```  which can be added to your configuration and export from emacs. I use doom-emacs configured  with ```(org +pandoc)``` but I am not pushing you to that (but useful if you need a fast solution).

Comment: Okay, thanks, I’ve installed `ox-pandoc`. What should I do to make emacs use it?

Comment: Please do _not_ evolve a question by implementing comment suggestions and then saying, in effect, "I tried that and ran into this other problem: XYZ." The question should now be deleted/closed or edited to remove the additional questions.

Comment: I see what you mean. I would argue that the edit up there reflects an _answer_ being evolved (solving the problem with pandoc), rather than a _question_ being evolved (how to get the `physics` package to work, etc.). I also believe the pandoc suggestion is useful for anybody else who ends up on this page trying to solve the same problem. So how about: I delete the edit, and we can move the pandoc discussion to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've probably looked through every single piece of documentation related to Org Mode's LaTeX to HTML export and MathJax, and this is what I've got:

Launch Emacs, then open up your MathJax configuration using
`M-x org-customize`. Go to `Org Export` -> `Org Export HTML` -> `Org HTML MathJax template`. There, you will find a window where you can edit the MathJax config.

Change it up so it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    displayAlign: "%ALIGN",
    displayIndent: "%INDENT",

    extensions: ["[Contrib]/physics/physics.js"],

    "HTML-CSS": { scale: %SCALE,
                    linebreaks: { automatic: "%LINEBREAKS" },
                    webFont: "%FONT"
                   },
    SVG: {scale: %SCALE,
          linebreaks: { automatic: "%LINEBREAKS" },
          font: "%FONT"},
    NativeMML: {scale: %SCALE},
    TeX: { equationNumbers: {autoNumber: "%AUTONUMBER"},
           MultLineWidth: "%MULTLINEWIDTH",
           TagSide: "%TAGSIDE",
           TagIndent: "%TAGINDENT"}
         }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="%PATH"></script>
```

The important line to add is:

```
extensions: ["[Contrib]/physics/physics.js"],
```

When you're in this editing mode the `<return>` key might not add a whitespace character. Remember that you can always add one using the `C-o` shortcut.
After you're done select `[ Apply and save ]`. Now the `physics` package should be working properly.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this works for my specific case (thanks to Ian’s comment):

1. Install the package `ox-pandoc`.
2. Customize the option `org-pandoc-options-for-html5` to include `mathjax` set to `t`.
3. Run the command `org-pandoc-export-to-html5`.