# Latex rendition on HTML export

Tags: org-export, latex, html

In Latex pdf export (C-c C-e l o) `$m$` renders correctly as italics *m* but in HTML export (C-c C-e h o) it renders as Roman `m`.

Reverse slash Latex formulas like $\mathbb{N}$ render fine in both Latex and HTML.

How can I fix this so that $m$ renders as *m* in HTML too?

---

**UPDATE**

This appears to be a Mac OSX Chrome issue. Safari renders the page correctly. I signed out of my Chrome account but the same issue remained. [In this video](https://youtu.be/h6F5Ubj7gqM) you can see that when I refresh the page Chrome briefly renders the page correctly but then it reverts back to the Roman font styling (The video is in slow motion).

---

I use this header for both exports:

```
#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-2.org
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cavendish-deneyi.com/css/worg-classic-new.css"/>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: $m +0 = m$ renders the `m` as italic in both PDF and HTML export here. Are you using MathJax in your HTML export?

Comment: @NickD I'm not sure. Some sources say mathjax is default in org. This page https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/start.html gives a script to add to `<head>`. I did that but nothing changed. How do I activate mathjax?

Comment: @NickD I found this answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/66416/36380 where they tell how to open mathjax options. I did that but I was scared to change anything. Nothing made sense.

Comment: @NickD "By default, Org loads MathJax from jsDelivr," https://orgmode.org/manual/Math-formatting-in-HTML-export.html

Comment: The question is: does your HTML file load the MathJax Javascript library? If it does, then your math should be rendered through the library and so your `m` should be italic. If it loads the library and your `m` is not italic, then we have to search harder for the reason. In that case, please post a short Org mode file that misbehaves for you, so others can try it and see if it also misbehaves for them.

Comment: So check the HTML file that is produced and see if it contains the following: `<script
  id="MathJax-script"
  async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
</script>`. You might also try `\(m+0 = m\)` instead of the dollar signs.

Comment: @NickD No. I checked the HTML file, it only contains Mathjax options, but not the script above. Can this be related to hosting? I contacted the hosting company and they said Mathjax was not supported in shared servers. But in this case, you should not be seeing $m$ as italics, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150295/discussion-between-nickd-and-zeynel).

Comment: @NickD I updated the question. Thanks again for the help.